# regular expressions in property attributes for asp.net mvc

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, custom-data-attribute

I want to prevent white space and special characters from a username, but I don't know how to do it in one data attribute and asp.net mvc only allows 1 regular expression attribute per property.

```
    [Required()]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = "Min 6 and max 10 characters")]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [RegularExpression(@"(\S)+", ErrorMessage = "White space is not allowed")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[\%\/\\\&\?\,\'\;\:\!\-]+$", ErrorMessage = "No special characters")]
    [Remote("IsUsernameDuplicate", "Account", HttpMethod = "Get", ErrorMessage = "The username is already in use")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
```

***EDIT 1***
I have changed my attributes to

```
    [Required()]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Minimum length is 5")]
    [MaxLength(12, ErrorMessage = "Maximum length is 12")]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9_]$", ErrorMessage = "Hey, no funny symbol stuff")]
    [Remote("IsUsernameDuplicate", "Account", HttpMethod = "Get", ErrorMessage = "The username is already in use")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
```

but I'm getting a error when typing in chuck and pressing tab

[image]

***EDIT 2***

solved it with a reg ex of ^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$

Comment: What are the allowed characters ? Also give some valid username examples.

Comment: Instead of saying what characters are not allowed, you should say what characters are allowed. For example, `^[\w.@_]+$` (which allows all numbers, alphabetic letters, dot, underscore, and the at sign). But if you really want to combine them, you can just use `\s` inside a `[^negated character class]`.

Comment: You removed the size `{6,10}`. New size will be `{5,12}`. Regex will be `^[A-Za-z0-9_]{5,12}$`.

Answer (score 0):

Regex for username with `A-Za-z0-9` and only `_` allowed( like most username ) would be.

**Regex:** `^[A-Za-z0-9_]{5,12}$`

Since your min and max length is checked you can use `^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$`.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dV3kW7/2)

Comment: I tried adding this [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9_]{6,10}$", ErrorMessage = "Hey, no funny symbol stuff")] but it still throws a validation error message on some regular characters

Comment: what does the {6,10} do?

Comment: Well I did asked you which characters you want to allow ?

Comment: `{6,10}` means minimum 6 and maximum 10.

Comment: can I take it out, I already have other attributes for min and max length.

Comment: I wont suggest taking it out since it will do no harm. Taking out **might** create some problems.

Comment: I'm having a problem with this reg ex. See my edit above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105942/discussion-between-noob-and-user1186050).

Comment: Why did you removed the `{6,10}` size ? Now you should add size like this `[A-Za-z0-9_]{5,12}`.